# Быстрое сравнение экземпляров класса по значению

Tags: c#

Как сравнить два объекта по значению без непосредственного написания метода сравнения каждого значения?

```
TableMain aa = new TableMain { id = 5 };
TableMain bb = new TableMain { id = 5 };
if (/* Что написать здесь? */) ...
```

Comment: поясните детальней, что конкретно вы хотите сделать? Переопределить equals? Сравнивать классы как структуры?

Comment: Нужно сравнить два объекта класса TableMain, по их значениям. Если я вас правильно понял, то да, сравнить их как структуры.

Comment: что значит "сравнивать по их значениям"?  - нет такого понятия как "значение класса". Если вам надо, чтобы ваши типы вели себя как структуры - то и создавайте их структурами

Comment: Не правильно выразился, нужно сравнить экземпляры класса TableMain, например сравнить экземпляр aa и bb по все его атрибутам(id...), без написания метода перебора строк.

Comment: без написания метода (или без каких либо других телодвижений) вы не сможете сравнивать ссылочные типы как значимые, из коробки ничего такого нет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать это с помощью рефлексии, да она не быстрая, но метод для сравнения можно создать один раз и закешировать. Если у вас в коде много таких сравнений, то это не самый плохой вариант:

```
static class ComparerEx
{
    public static bool IsEqual<T>(this T obj1, T obj2)
        => ComparerImpl<T>.IsEqual(obj1, obj2);

    private class ComparerImpl<T>
    {
        static ComparerImpl()
        {
            var parameters = new[]
            {
                Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x"),
                Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "y")
            };
            Expression body = Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool));
            var memberTypes = new[] { MemberTypes.Field, MemberTypes.Property };
            foreach (var member in typeof(T).GetMembers().Where(m => memberTypes.Contains(m.MemberType)))
                body = Expression.AndAlso(body,
                    Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameters[0], member),
                        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameters[1], member)));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, bool>>(body, parameters);
            //Console.WriteLine(lambda);
            IsEqual = lambda.Compile();
        }

        public static readonly Func<T, T, bool> IsEqual;
    }
}
```

После этого можно будет писать что-то вроде:

```
class A
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public int Field1;
}
```

и

```
var a1 = new A { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = "1", Field1 = 11 };
var a2 = new A { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = "1", Field1 = 11 };
var r = a1.IsEqual(a2); // вернет true
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Comment: после слов _можно сделать с помощью рефлексии_ ожидал увидеть только рефлексию, а не сборку дерева выражения и его компиляцию :)

Comment: Без кеширования была бы только рефлексия, правда, там отдельно пришлось бы писать доступ к полям и доступ к свойствам, в Expressions, благо, есть `MakeMemberAccess` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Там в принципе можно было и обычными Property или Field выражениями обойтись, в зависимости от самих классов