# C# копирование свойств с помощью reflection

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Необходимо копировать все публичные свойства из одного объекта в другой объект такого же типа.
В результате раздумий родился следующий код.

```
public static class PropertyCopy<T> where T : new()
{
    private static readonly PropertyInfo[] _propertyInfo;

    static PropertyCopy()
    {
        _propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.CanWrite).ToArray();
    }

    public static void CopyAllProperties(T from, T to)
    {
        foreach (var prop in _propertyInfo)
        {
            prop.SetValue(to, prop.GetValue(from));
        }
    }
}
```

Идея тут такая, когда впервые вызывается метод CopyAllProperties, в конструкторе создается массив со всеми необходимыми для копирования свойствами PropertyInfo[]. И при последующем вызове метода CopyAllProperties для этого типа массив создаваться уже не будет, все свойства уже выбраны и готовы в копированию. И по идее большая часть накладных расходов на производительность через reflection в данном случае снимается.

Копировать предполагается очень много раз, поэтому вопрос производительности важен. Копирование не нужно глубокое, то есть для ссылочного типа копируется ссылка.

Этот код вполне работает и выглядит красиво.

Правильное ли предположение про "большая часть накладных расходов на производительность через reflection в данном случае снимается"?

Либо все таки вся проблема будет в prop.SetValue(to, prop.GetValue(from))?

Comment: [automapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) ?

Comment: @tym32167 использование automapper мне кажется избыточной для данной ситуации. Тут же типы одинаковые. К тому же интересует академический интерес, насколько разумен данный подход.

Comment: Данный подход будет тормозить на prop.SetValue(to, prop.GetValue(from)). Необходимо генерировать код чтения и записи свойств, деревья выражений хорошо подходят, и кешировать его.

Comment: Если интерес академический, то решение вам выше подсказали уже, скомпилированное дерево выражений будет быстрей рефлексии

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо. Нашел ответы почти на все вопросы по теме здесь http://mattwarren.org/2016/12/14/Why-is-Reflection-slow/

Comment: Связанный топик (сравнение всех публичных свойств объектов): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864907/218063

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет. Основные расходы на reflection случаются не в момент `GetProperties` (как раз метаданные средой выполнения кешируются), а при обращении к свойству через `SetValue` и `GetValue`.

Способ ускорения таких вещей известен - генерация кода на лету. Проще всего использовать Linq Expressions:

```
public static class PropertyCopy<T>
{
    private static readonly Action<T, T> copier;

    static PropertyCopy()
    {
        var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "from");
        var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "to");

        var props = from property in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    where property.CanRead && property.CanWrite
                    select Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(p2, property), Expression.Property(p1, property));

        copier = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, T>>(Expression.Block(props), p1, p2).Compile();
    }

    public static void CopyAllProperties(T from, T to) => copier(from, to);
}
```