# Как собрать выражение для конкатенации свойств произвольного класса?

Tags: c#, linq, expressions

Хочу с помощью деревьев выражений LINQ сгенерировать делегат, который будет делать конкатенацию всех строковых свойств произвольного типа:

```
static Func<T,string> TestConcat<T>(T obj)
{
    var type=obj.GetType();
    LabelTarget label = Expression.Label(typeof(string), "ResultLabel");
    var param = Expression.Parameter(type);
    var resultExp=Expression.Variable(typeof(string), "result");
    Expression assign = Expression.Assign(resultExp, Expression.Constant(""));
    foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
    {
        var member = Expression.Property(param, prop);
        assign = Expression.Add(assign, member, typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(assign.ToString());
    var block = Expression.Block(new[] { resultExp, param }, new[] { Expression.Label(label, assign), assign  });
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T,string>>(block, param).Compile();
}
```

Ловлю NullReferenceException, но не понимаю в чем проблема...

Подскажите, как правильно сделать?

Comment: Сильно не вчитывался, но выглядит так себе. Вот здесь можно посмотреть пример сборки выражения: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864907/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ну там какой-то простой пример... А тут у меня акумуляция...

Comment: Покажите пример входного класса и какое выражение вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну хочу на вход передать класс, который содержит только текстовые свойства. Потом сгенерировать делегат, который будет для данного типа суммировать строки свойств между собой и возвращать 1 результирующую строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы напихали лишнего в свой метод. У меня работает такой код:

```
static class ConcatEx
{
    public static string ConcatProps<T>(this T obj) => ConcatPropsImpl<T>.ConcatProps(obj);

    private class ConcatPropsImpl<T>
    {
        static ConcatPropsImpl()
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            Expression body = Expression.Constant(string.Empty, typeof(string));
            var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
            foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
                body = Expression.Add(body, Expression.Property(parameter, prop), method);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(body, parameter);
            ConcatProps = lambda.Compile();
        }

        public static readonly Func<T, string> ConcatProps;
    }
}
```

Использовать так:

```
var test = new Test { A = "A", B = "B", C = "C" };
Console.WriteLine(test.ConcatProps());
```

Ну или, если вам нужна именно функция, а не результат ее выполнения, то берите `ConcatEx.ConcatProps<Test>`

Но, мне кажется, на выходе не самый эффективный метод получается (`string.Concat(string.Concat(string.Concat("", x.A), x.B), x.C)`)

Наверное, лучше вызывать перегрузку `string.Concat`, принимающую массив:

```
static class ConcatEx
{
    public static string ConcatProps<T>(this T obj) => ConcatPropsImpl<T>.ConcatProps(obj);

    private class ConcatPropsImpl<T>
    {
        static ConcatPropsImpl()
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(object[]) });
            var props = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(prop => Expression.Property(parameter, prop));
            var array = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), props);
            var body = Expression.Call(method, array);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(body, parameter);
            ConcatProps = lambda.Compile();
        }

        public static readonly Func<T, string> ConcatProps;
    }
}
```

Comment: А выражения, по идее, должны шустрее выполняться нежели обычная рефлексия, за счет того, что выражение "знает" о полях и получает все естественным путем?

Comment: Не совсем, `typeof(T).GetProperties()` — это рефлексия всё же. Если вы оставите код так как сделано у вас в теле вопроса, то при каждом вызове метода будет перебор свойств через рефлексию, сборка и компиляция выражения. И это будет медленно. Если же вы оформите это в виде статического класса, как у меня, то выражение гарантированно будет создано один раз и закешировано в делегат. Все последующие вызовы будут быстрые — по сути они будут вызовами делегата.

Comment: А зачем статический класс? Если я верну откомпилированный делегат, а вызывающий код его закеширует сам, то по идее, все четко должно быть.

Comment: Ну или так, да. Но при первом запуске в любом случае здесь перебор свойств через рефлексию и компиляция делегата из выражения, что имеет некоторые накладные расходы.